# What is the difference between tonic and phasic firing?

Tags: dopamine

I am reading about dopamine, and I have realized that dopaminergic neurons can fire phasically or tonically. What is the difference between these two modes of firing?

Answer (score 12):

Tonic firing typically occurs without presynaptic input and can be viewed at as background activity. Tonic activity is often characterized by a steady action potential firing at a constant frequency. Note that not all neurons may have tonic activity at rest. It may serve as keeping a steady background level of a certain neurotransmitter or it can serve as a mechanism where both an inhibition or increase in presynaptic input can be transmitted. When a neuron is silent at rest, only an increase in presynaptic activity can be transmitted postsynaptically.

In contrast, phasic firing occurs after a neuron is activated due to presynaptic activity and it incurs activity on top of any background activity a neuron may have. It is typically restricted to one, a few, or a short burst of action potentials, whereafter the activity quickly returns to the resting state.

<sub>**Reference**

[Tsai *et al*., *Science* (2017); **324**: 1080-4](http://med.stanford.edu/content/dam/sm/delecea/documents/Tsai_2009_Science.pdf)</sub>

Comment: Could you please explain what causes tonic firing? I.e. how can a neuron depolarize itself?

Comment: @VivekSubramanian: cyclic changes in restig membrane potential or inputs from other neurons

Comment: @AliceD , from the paper you reference, both tonic and phasic activity seem evoked, instead of tonic activity being passive background activity. The definition I would extract from that paper is instead that phasic activity consists of faster firing, maybe only bursting, and tonic firing is lower-frequency firing:   Caption figure 2: "(D) Whole-cell recording of DA neurons showing spontaneous activity and tonic and
phasic firing evoked by 1-Hz and 50-Hz light flash trains, respectively". Or: "low-frequency tonic activity and phasic bursts of action potentials" (first page)

Comment: Maybe tonic = constant for a longer duration (like muscle tone), whereas phasic = in phases ?